# Summing a list of values, with for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop

New to C and I need some guidance. I understand why the my code is outputting "55" instead of "40"; but I have no idea how to fix this. Any advice? Some of the variables listed are obsolete, and were simply put in to experiment with. Just to clarify, lower/upper are just the min/max values for the range.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int sum = 0;
int main() {
    int n = 10;
    int m = 2;
    int i, x;
    int upper;
    int lower;
    int lower1[100];
    int upper1[100];
    int sum_p =0;

    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        lower = 1 + (i - 1) * (n / m);
        lower1[i] = lower;
        upper = i * (n / m);
        upper1[i] = upper;

        if (i == m) {
            upper = n;
            upper1[i] = upper;
        }
        else {
            upper = i * (n / m);
            upper1[i] = upper;
        }
    }

   for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
       sum += i;
   }

   printf("The total sum is: %d\n",sum);

   for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
       printf("Range is %d to %d\n", lower1[i], upper1[i]);

       for(x = lower1[i]; x <= upper1[i]; ++x)
           sum_p += x;

       printf("Sum:%d\n",sum_p);
   }
}
```

This code outputs:

```
The total sum is: 55
Range is 1 to 5
Sum:15
Range is 6 to 10
Sum:55
```

My desired output is:

```
The total sum is: 55
Range is 1 to 5
Sum: 15
Range is 6 to 10 /*6+7+8+9+10*/
Sum: 40
```

Comment: You're missing some obvious information like the definition and contents of the arrays you're referencing

Comment: I apologize! I will post my whole code right now!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just used your method of resetting sum_p to zero between iterations. It worked. I can't believe I did not think of that. Thank you for your help/ patience!

Comment: Please, remember that in C array indices start from **0**, not 1. It may not be a problem in this particular snippet, but it's a known source of bugs in general.

Answer (score 2):

`sum_p` is not reset to zero between cases.